# Why is my sobel filter output so bright when using separable kernels?

Tags: c++, image-processing, computer-vision, convolution, sobel

I'm trying to implement the Sobel filter from scratch. I'm using the separable filters described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator#Technical_details.

Here is my original image converted to greyscale: 
[greyscale image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcEJX.png)

The output for my Sobel X-gradient is fine: [x-gradient sobel filtered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaE8q.png)

However, my image for the Sobel y-gradient is not correct: [y-gradient sobel filtered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLWkT.png)

It seems to me like the pixel values are too high. This is what the y-gradient image looks like after the horizontal convolution with the kernel `[1, 2, 1]`, but before the vertical convolution: [y-gradient horizontal only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajMt3.png)

Here is the code. Note that for the y-gradient I just copy-pasted the x-gradient code and swapped which kernel gets used first (as the Wikipedia page denotes):

```
int sobel_1[3] = {1, 0, -1};
int sobel_2[3] = {1, 2, 1};

Image Image::sobel_x(){
    Image grayscale = this->grayscale();
    Image sobel_x = Image(m_width, m_height, m_max);

    int r_delta[3] = {-1, 0, 1};
    int c_delta[3] = {-1, 0, 1};

    for (int row = 0; row < m_height; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < m_width; col++){
            Color new_color = Color();

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){   
                int new_c = col + c_delta[i]; 

                if (new_c >= 0 && new_c < m_width){
                    new_color = new_color + (grayscale.getRGB(row, new_c) * sobel_1[i]);
                }
            }

            new_color = Color(abs(new_color.get_r()), abs(new_color.get_g()), abs(new_color.get_b()));
            new_color.clamp();

            sobel_x.setColor(row, col, new_color);
        }
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < m_height; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < m_width; col++){
            Color new_color = Color();

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                int new_r = row + r_delta[i]; 

                if (new_r >= 0 && new_r < m_height){
                    new_color = new_color + (sobel_x.getRGB(new_r, col) * sobel_2[i]);
                }
            }

            new_color = Color(abs(new_color.get_r()), abs(new_color.get_g()), abs(new_color.get_b()));
            new_color.clamp();
            new_color = new_color / 8;

            sobel_x.setColor(row, col, new_color);
        }
    }

    return sobel_x;
}

Image Image::sobel_y(){
    Image grayscale = this->grayscale();
    Image sobel_y = Image(m_width, m_height, m_max);

    int r_delta[3] = {-1, 0, 1};
    int c_delta[3] = {-1, 0, 1};

    for (int row = 0; row < m_height; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < m_width; col++){
            Color new_color = Color();

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){   
                int new_c = col + c_delta[i]; 

                if (new_c >= 0 && new_c < m_width){
                    new_color = new_color + (grayscale.getRGB(row, new_c) * sobel_2[i]);
                }
            }

            new_color = Color(abs(new_color.get_r()), abs(new_color.get_g()), abs(new_color.get_b()));
            new_color.clamp();

            sobel_y.setColor(row, col, new_color);
        }
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < m_height; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < m_width; col++){
            Color new_color = Color();

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                int new_r = row + r_delta[i]; 

                if (new_r >= 0 && new_r < m_height){
                    new_color = new_color + (sobel_y.getRGB(new_r, col) * sobel_1[i]);
                }
            }

            new_color = Color(abs(new_color.get_r()), abs(new_color.get_g()), abs(new_color.get_b()));
            new_color.clamp();
            new_color = new_color / 8;

            sobel_y.setColor(row, col, new_color);
        }
    }

    return sobel_y;
}
```

Comment: I see `clamp` and `abs` in your code. Both should be removed, they’re incorrect. Put your output pixels in a signed int16 or larger type (I like to use `float`). After computing all values you can decide how to scale the output to the display range. This is the reason you get different results depending on the order in which you apply the two 2D filters (smoothing & derivative).

Comment: Yes, the language is C++. Thanks for that. Why does it matter type I store my RGB values in? Won't I always scale my values between 0 and 1 in the end, even if I store the RGB in floats?

Comment: If you store your values as int and scale them between 0 and 1 there won’t be much information left...  I don’t know what type `Image` is here, but more often than not it’ll be a uint8. You can’t store negative values there. Also you need to be careful with scaling values, as that affects the magnitude of the gradient you compute.